# mongoexport exports unwanted siblings in the document tree

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoexport

`mongoexport` seems to be exporting unwanted siblings when interested fields are explicitly specified. I have tried this with `mongo-2.6`, `mongo-3.0.2`, `mongo-3.2.8` an all express the same behaviour.

For example:

```
./mongoexport --host my.mongo.host:10099  --db mydb --collection mycoll --fields myfield --query '{"some.attribute.filter":"some-attribute-value"}' --limit 1 --out /tmp/myexport.json
```

This exports the entire JSON for `myfield`.

```
./mongoexport --host my.mongo.host:10099  --db mydb --collection mycoll --fields myfield.desiredSubField --query '{"some.attribute.filter":"some-attribute-value"}' --limit 1 --out /tmp/myexport.json
```

This also exports the entire JSON for `myfield`, instead of just exporting the nested field `myfield.desiredSubField`.

Interestingly the same works when `--type=csv`. However I am interested in a JSON output.

Is this behaviour by design or am I doing something wrong?
If this is by design, are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this behaviour by design or am I doing something wrong?

Yes, this is by design as documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--fields .
*--fields* only supports top level field extraction.

> If this is by design, are there any other alternatives?

**Alternatives to consider may include:**

- extracting data programmatically using mongoDB supported drivers. (For more information please see docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/)
- using aggregation to create a new collection to export where a subfield could be renamed by applying $project for computed fields documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-computed-fields

**Here is an example for aggregation:**

```
db.coll.aggregate([
      {$match : {"some.attribute.filter":"some-attribute-value"}},
      {$project : {"new-field-name":"$myfield.desiredSubField", _id:0 }}, 
      {$out : "new-collection-name"}
])
```

In the mongo shell with a *testrc* collection creating a new *nested* collection

```
> db.testrc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578d1ac48c3757a609a36286"), "a" : { "b" : 3 }, "b" : { "a" : 3 }, "c" : { "a" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fc7faed1d015678b0252a"), "a" : { "b" : 3, "c" : 10, "d" : 11 }, "b" : { "a" : 3, "c" : 10, "d" : 11 }, "c" : { "a" : 1 } }

> db.testrc.aggregate([{$match:{"b.a":{$gte:0}}},{$project : {"b_a":"$b.a", _id:0 }}, {$out :"nested"}])

> db.nested.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fc8ad1ecfad36cde071c9"), "b_a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fc8ad1ecfad36cde071ca"), "b_a" : 3 }
```

and then

```
$ mongoexport --db testr --collection nested --fields b_a --out ba.json
```

would lead to

```
$ cat ba.json
{"_id":{"$oid":"578fc8ad1ecfad36cde071c9"},"b_a":3.0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"578fc8ad1ecfad36cde071ca"},"b_a":3.0}
```

which still includes the "_id" field, but no longer shows siblings nor parent documents.